# How to get rid of 404 error in my console for images without extension files

Tags: html, angularjs, image, http-status-code-404

In my angular web app I am using this `<img ng-src="{{ image }}">` code to handle the `images` from the `controller`.

It works totally fine even if I do not include an extension type also my `controller` only receives `image` name without the extension type so I'm totally clueless if it is a `.jpeg` or `.png` etc., so browser returns a lot of `404` in the console and it's just totally nasty. How do I get rid of them without including the extension name of the image? Thanks.

Comment: Why the `image` variable was set to wrong path?

Comment: What do you mean wrong path? Its totally working. @MoshFeu

Comment: `my controller is expecting different image types such as .jpeg, .png, .gif `. Who send to the controller images with other types?

Comment: @MoshFeu sorry about the confusion please read edit.

Comment: If you try to get those urls in the browser, you get the image?

Comment: Nope if you're talking about pasting the url on the browser. @MoshFeu

Comment: So, the problem is with the urls and no with your code..